# Invalid Object Name Error - EntityFrameworkCore 2.0

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-core

Howdee, I'm having an issue with entity framework telling me that the objects don't exist on my database when they do exist and I have mapped the names using the .ToTable method. Below is how I'm injecting the context into my controller:

In Startup.cs => ConfigureServices

```
var connection = @"Server={myserver};
                            Initial Catalog={mydb};Persist Security Info=False;
                            User ID={myId};Password={mypassword};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
                            Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";

services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

In MyController.cs

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("myroute")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser([FromBody] MyUser myUser)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = _context.MyUser
                .Where(y => y.UserName == myUser.UserName)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.UserManager.CreateAsync(myUser);

                if (result.Succeeded) return Ok();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            _logger.LogError($"Create User Error: {ex}");
        }

        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

In MyContext.cs

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<MyApi.DataAccess.Entities.MyUser> MyUser { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<MyApi.DataAccess.Entities.MyUser>()
            .ToTable("dbo.MyUsers");
    }
}
```

This is my first time getting into asynchronous programming in server side code so there's a chance it could be something there? I've tested the connection string in a console application and I'm able to connect to the database via the console application (C# .Net) so I'm assuming that it is not the issue (Plus, I grabbed the connection string straight from Azure). Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Are you using Code First approach ?

Comment: You will need to add the exact exception message if you expect our help

Comment: wowzers - some of you guys are insanely quick to down-vote on stack overflow. the exception message is "Invalid Object Name 'dbo.MyUsers'". I'm not using a code first approach @EhsanUllahNazir. I'm not a fan of migrations so I tend to manage databases myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In EF (Core) configuration (both data annotations and fluent API), the table name is separated from the schema.

Remove the `"dbo."` from the table name and use the `ToTable` overload with `name` and `schema` arguments:

```
.ToTable("MyUsers", "dbo");
```

Or taking into account that `dbo` is the default schema (if not configured differently), simply:

```
.ToTable("MyUsers");
```

As it is currently, it considers table `dbo.dbo.MyUsers` which of course does not exist.

Comment: ahhh, that makes sense. I was so used to putting the schema and table name in a single string when working entity framework in previous apps that I never even thought to look at the method signature to see if it had changed. Appreciate the help Ivan!

Comment: Ack this got me too, just started using .net Core and I could not understand why it would not take schema.table name.  Thanks!